# trying to change the color of box on touch in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to change the box color from black to blue when the pointer touches it and then when it leaves it it must return to black again .. here is my code

```html
<html>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("box").style.background = "blue";
    
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="box" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid;background-color:black" onblur="myFunction()"></div>
<label id="lab">arrow</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `onblur`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS, not JS for this:

```css
#box:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<label id="lab">arrow</label>
```

Comment: This is correct and I realize his example is a div, except I would also target `:focus` in case it is a button or a link and not a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS without any need for JavaScript:

```
#box {background: black;}
#box:hover {background: blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, what you want is onMouseOver and onMouseOut:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("box").style.background = "blue";

}
function changeBack(){
document.getElementById("box").style.background = "black";
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="box" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid;background-color:black" onMouseOver="myFunction()"
  onMouseOut="changeBack()"


></div>
<label id="lab">arrow</label>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ho2rwxLo/